# How would I create even borders for uneven content boxes?

Tags: html, css

I am about halfway through completing a course for learning HTML and CSS, the first time I've ever tried programming, so pardon the (probably) simple problem I have.

I am creating navigation tabs for a fictional website, the tabs being "Menu", "Nutrition", "Order", and "Locations". As you can see, each tab would be a different size because the content varies. I am trying to make a border for each tab, so that the borders would be the same height and width for each one, effectively lining up as four congruent rectangles with words inside of them. The code in HTML for this part that I am working with is:

```
<nav>
   <span><a href="#">MENU</a></span>
   <span><a href="#">NUTRITION</a></span>
   <span><a href="#">ORDER</a></span>
   <span><a href="#">LOCATIONS</a></span>
</nav>
```

The code I currently have for CSS that would effect this is:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

,

```
nav span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 13px 0px;
}
```

and

```
nav a {
  color: #666666;
  border: 1px solid rgb(202, 202, 202);
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0px 3px;
}
```

[This is the resulting visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qydr2.png)

How would I make it so that the borders for each tab would be congruent and in line with each other?

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 13px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav a {
  color: #666666;
  border: 1px solid rgb(202, 202, 202);
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0px 3px;
  text-decoration: none; 
  display: inline-block;  
}
```

https://codepen.io/stargroup0075/pen/MWwLxMd

Answer (score 0):

You want to

1. Give the elements with the borders (`<a />`) `display: block;`, which causes them to occupy the maximum horizontal space available
2. Give a container of the blocks (`<nav />`) `display: inline-block;`, which makes the container shrink-wrap its content
3. Give the parent of `<nav />` (in your HTML example there is no parent, so I assume it's `<body />`) `text-align: center;`, which centers the `<nav />`, like with your original code.

The resulting CSS would look something like this:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box }
body { text-align: center }   /* Centers child inline content */
nav { display: inline-block } /* Shrink-to-fit content */

nav span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin: 13px 0px;
}

nav a {
    display: block; /* Take up maximum horizontal space */
    color: #666666;
    border: 1px solid rgb(202, 202, 202);
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0px 3px;
}
```